# How do I fit an image inside of a dialog box in Angular Material?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I'm trying to fit an image completely inside of a dialog window without overflowing off the screen or having scroll wheels appear on each side. I want the Dialog window to never fill up the entire screen but most of it (like 80% either axis). But I'm stuck on the images never auto sizing to fit in that box.

[image]

Currently everything I try will show a bar on the right side if the height of the image is to big.

Ideally I'd want to have an image that auto resizes itself to fit in the screen.

Here's my Dialog css

```
.full-width-dialog .mat-dialog-container {
  // max-width: 80vw !important;
  max-height: 80vh !important;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

And my Image container css

```
.image-cont {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0;

  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
}
```

And the html template for the dialog box.

```
<div class="image-cont">
  <img
    id="{{ data.id }}"
    src="...SOME_IMAGE_LIBRARY___/id/{{ data.id }}/{{ data.width }}/{{ data.height}}" 
  />
</div>
```

Note the src will always be an image much larger than the screen.

Comment: You could make it `background-size: cover;` via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really sure how to use that? Just adding `background-size: cover;` to either the img or the image-cont container didn't really do anything.

Comment: You would have to make the image a background image of your `.image-cont` wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by forcing it a little bit.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="3vw" class="dialog">
  <div class="image-cont">
    <img
      id="{{ data.id }}"
      src="https://picsum.photos/id/{{ data.id }}/{{ data.original_width }}/{{
        data.original_height
      }}"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Then for CSS

```
.image-cont {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
}

.dialog {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

and

```
.full-width-dialog .mat-dialog-container {
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Applied fully to the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the overflow on the dialog box to hidden if you don't want to make it a background image set to cover like Dominik mentioned. This will hide the scroll bar.

```
.full-width-dialog .mat-dialog-container {
  // max-width: 80vw !important;
  max-height: 80vh !important;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will cut off images that are larger in height than width. In the case where the height is larger I would like it to maximize height to screen and decrease width to fit.

Comment: I see, I got caught on the scroll bar in your question. Do you have a live example of the code you are working on?

Comment: I don't have it hosted anywhere but I just uploaded the code to [github1s](https://github1s.com/jskyjohnson/AngularProject), the only files with css that would change things are the `theme.scss` in root at the bottom under `.full-width-dialog .mat-dialog-container` since that's added in the gallery-dash.component.ts when the dialog is opened, and the `dialog-view.component.scss.` Its a bit different from what's shown earlier but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting the height and width of the parent div to 100%?

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to do anything.